# Spark gives Error when creating DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have downloaded spark version 2.3.1 and hadoop version 2.7 and java jdk 8.
Every thing works fine for simple exercises, but when i tried to create dataframe. it start to though error.
the following code runs with out error.

```
import numpy as np

TOTAL = 1000000
dots = sc.parallelize([2.0 * np.random.random(2) - 1.0 for i in range(TOTAL)]).cache()
print("Number of random points:", dots.count())

stats = dots.stats()
print('Mean:', stats.mean())
print('stdev:', stats.stdev())
```

but when i tried the following code requires the input to change into dataframe

```
df = sc.parallelize([Row(name='ab',age=20), Row(name='ab',age=20)]).toDF()
```

it throws the following error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you were missing import for Row.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = sc.parallelize([Row(name='ab',age=20), Row(name='ab',age=20)]).toDF() 
df.show()
```

Result:

```
+---+----+
|age|name|
+---+----+
| 20|  ab|
| 20|  ab|
+---+----+
```